# Difference between an Output & an Export

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In CloudFormation we have the ability to output some values from a template so that they can be retrieved by other processes, stacks, etc. This is typically the name of something, maybe a URL or something generated during stack creation (deployment), etc.

We also have the ability to 'export' from a template. What is the difference between returning a value as an 'output' vs as an 'export'?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Regular output values can't be references from other stacks**. They can be useful when you **chain** or **nest** your stacks and their scope/visibility is local. Exported outputs are visible globally within account and region, and can be used by any future stack you are going to deploy.

**Chaining**

When you chain your stacks, you deploy one stack, take it outputs, and use as input parameters to the second stack you are going to deploy.

For example, let's say you have two templates called `instance.yaml` and `eip.yaml`. The `instance.yaml` outputs its instance-id (no export), while `eip.yaml` takes instance id as an input parameter.

To deploy them both, you have to chain them:

1. Deploy `instance.yaml` and wait for its completion.
2. Note it outputs values (i.e. instance-id) - usually done programmatically, not manually.
3. Deploy `eip.yaml` and pass instance-id as its input parameter.

**Nesting**

When you nest stacks you will have a parent template and a child template. Child stack will be created from inside of the parent stack. In this case the child stack will produce some outputs (not exports) for the parent stack to use.

For example, lets use again `instance.yaml` and `eip.yaml`. But this time `eip.yaml` will be parent and `instance.yaml` will be child. Also `eip.yaml` does not take any input parameters, but `instance.yaml`  outputs its instance-id (not export)

In this case, to deploy them you do the following:

1. Upload child template (`instance.yaml`) to s3
2. In `eip.yaml` create the child instance stack using [AWS::CloudFormation::Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html) and the s3 url from step 1.

This way `eip.yaml` will be able to access the instance-id from the outputs of the nested stack using `GetAtt`.

**Cross-referencing**

When you cross-reference stacks, you have one stack that exports it outputs so that they can be used by any other stack in the same region and account.

For example, lets use again `instance.yaml` and `eip.yaml`. `instance.yaml` is going to export its output (instance-id). To use the instance-id `eip.yaml` will have to use [ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) in its template without the need for any input parameters or nested stacks.

In this case, to deploy them you do the following:

1. Deploy `instance.yaml` and wait till it completes.
2. Deploy `eip.yaml` which will import the instance-id.

Altough **cross-referencing** seems very useful, it has one major issue, which is that its very difficult to update or delete cross-referenced [stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html):

> After another stack imports an output value, you **can't delete the stack that is exporting the output value or modify the exported output value**. All of the imports must be removed before you can delete the exporting stack or modify the output value.

This is very problematic if you are starting your design and your templates can change often.

**When to use which?**

Use cross-references (exported values) when you have some **global resources** that are going to be shared among many stacks in a given region and account. Also they should not change often as they are difficult to modify. Common examples are: a global bucket for centralized logging location, a VPC.

Use nested stack (not exported outputs) when you have some **common components** that you often deploy, but each time they can be a bit different. Examples are: ALB, a bastion host instance, vpc interface endpoint.

Finally, chained stacks (not exported outputs) are useful for designing **loosely-coupled** templates, where you can mix and match templates based on new requirements.

Comment: Under nesting above, you stated child as eip.yml. Is that a typo ? In the paragraph above you stated child is instance.yml. So which is which? please clarify

Comment: @user3477108 Thanks. EIP template should be parent. Typo corrected.

Comment: In the numbered list under **Nesting**, you said to upload `eip.yaml` to S3, but then the next item says to use the S3 url in `eip.yml`. Isn't that a circular reference? Did you mean to say to upload the child `instance.yml` to S3 instead?

Comment: @TheUnknownDev Yep, I am pretty sure that is the case. I asked for the question to be edited and I see now that it has been.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html), use `export` **between stacks**, and use `output` with **nested stacks**.

#### Export

> To share information between stacks, export a stack's output values.
> Other stacks that are in the same AWS account and region can import
> the exported values.

#### Output

> With nested stacks, you deploy and manage all resources from a single
> stack. You can use outputs from one stack in the nested stack group as
> inputs to another stack in the group. This differs from exporting
> values.