# Cloudformation stack with nested resources fails to create

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to define some common resources (specifically, a couple of IAM roles) that will be shared between two environments, via a nested stack. The first environment to use the nested stack's resources creates ok, but the second one fails when trying to run the nested stack. Am I not understanding something about how nested stacks work, or am I just doing something wrong?

My nested stack is defined as:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Defines common resources shared between environments.

Parameters:
    ParentStage:
    Type: String
    Description: The Stage or environment name.
    Default: ""
    ParentVpcId:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
    Description: VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)
    Default: ""

Resources:

    LambdaFunctionSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
        GroupDescription: Identifies Lamdba functions to VPC resources
        GroupName: BBA-KTDO-SG-LambdaFunction
        VpcId: !Ref ParentVpcId

    RdsAccessSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
        GroupDescription: Allows Lambda functions access to RDS instances
        GroupName: BBA-KTDO-SG-RDS
        SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
            FromPort: 3306
            ToPort: 3306
            SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref LambdaFunctionSG
        VpcId: !Ref ParentVpcId
```

I've uploaded that YAML file to an S3 bucket, and I'm then trying to use it in two separate stack files (i.e. `app_dev.yaml` and `app_prod.yaml`) as:

```yaml
Resources:

    CommonResources:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
    Properties:
        TemplateURL: "https://my-buildbucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/common/common.yaml"
        Parameters:
        ParentStage: !Ref Stage
        ParentVpcId: !Ref VpcId
```

And referring to its outputs as (e.g):

```yaml
VpcConfig:
    SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt [ CommonResources, Outputs.LambdaFunctionSGId ]
```

The first environment creates fine, including the nested resources. When I try to run the second environment, it fails with error:

> Embedded stack
> arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:238165151424:stack/my-prod-stack-CommonResources-L94ZCIP0UD9W/f9d06dd0-994d-11eb-9802-02554f144c21
> was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to
> create: [LambdaExecuteRole, LambdaFunctionSG].

Is it not possible to share a single resource definition between two separate stacks like this, or have I just missed something in the implementation?

Comment: It may be a result of naming things. If you had a named IAM role, for example, the first would succeed but the second would fail. If you remove the name it will end with with a generated name based on the stack name and resource name (with random characters added).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jasonwadsworth mentioned that's correct names of the stacks are always amended with a random string at the end [AWS::CloudFormation::Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#aws-properties-stack-return-values) check the return values. Use `GetAtt` to get the name of the stack and construct the output. [How do I pass values between nested stacks within the same parent stack in AWS CloudFormation?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-nested-stacks-values/)

Plus use [aws cloudformation package](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) command for packaging the nested stacks,  no need to manually upload them to s3 bucket.

someting like

```sh
aws cloudformation package \
--template-file /path_to_template/template.json \
--s3-bucket bucket-name \
--output-template-file packaged-template.json
```

Take a look on the [cloudformation output exports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) as well in case you are curious [Difference between an Output & an Export](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62441460/2246345)

Comment: Thanks very much - I deleted the group name and now both stacks build. I was also already using `aws cloudformation package` for packaging up the lambda functions, but didn't realise I could also apply that to the stack template file, so that's taken another unnecessary step out of the deploy script :)